# What DLL contains the exceptions under Microsoft.Powershell.Command namespace?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using C# to execute the New-LocalUser cmdlet.  If the user already exists, this cmdlet will store an exception in the ErrorStream:

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
   powerShellInstance.AddCommand("New-LocalUser");
   powerShellInstance.AddParameter("Name", username);
   powerShellInstance.AddParameter("Password", password);

   PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
   output.DataAdded += OutputAdded;

   powerShellInstance.Invoke(null, output);

   if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
   {
       throw powerShellInstance.Streams.Error[0].Exception;
   }
}
```

When I print out the above exception type, it is Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.UserExistsException.  But I can't seem to find the DLL that contains this definition.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, run `New-LocalUser -?` in a PowerShell session to make sure that the assembly containing the type of interest is loaded.

Then run the following command:

```
[Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.UserExistsException].Assembly.Location
```

On my Windows 10 machine this yields:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts.dll
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a more elegant solution.  I just searched my computer for that DLL.  However, it didn't work even after I referenced the DLL.  For some reason, Visual Studio cannot see: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts. In any case, it worked once I copied the DLL to another location